# Get login who grantes privileges in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the login name who grants privileges in tables... I got this query:

```
select  princ.name
,       princ.type_desc
,       perm.permission_name
,       perm.state_desc
,       perm.class_desc
,       object_name(perm.major_id)
,       user_name(perm.grantor_principal_id)
from    sys.database_principals princ
left join
        sys.database_permissions perm
on      perm.grantee_principal_id = princ.principal_id
where name not in('public') and object_name(perm.major_id) is not null
```

It works, but if the login who granted a privileges is db_owner, the query prints: "dbo" but I need to print the login name.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't think this is possible to get the information that you're looking for from sys.database_permissions for the reasons that you've already discovered (namely that anyone in sysadmin maps to the dbo user in the database). If this is important to you, I'd set up something like event notifications or DDL triggers on grant/deny/revoke statements and log it.

Answer (score 0):

Logins and usernames are two different things while you seem to be confused by that. I would recommend reading this nice article and there are some examples, too:

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/understanding-usernames

Comment: Thanks for the link... alright, let's see: I understand when you create a login, you can map it in a database and automatically becomes a user database, right? well, I need to add to my query the login who grants privileges.... is it possible through the user database?... I'm so confused